# rsync Problems using Parameter backup-dir

Tags: rsync, backup

In all cases I use `rsync` it works like expected. And very fast. For example:

```shell
rsync -a --exclude='.*' --stats --progress --delete --backup --suffix="OLD" SOURCE TARGET
```

needs (with no difference in `SOURCE` and `TARGET` less than 1 second (70GB/500 Files/Folders).

But when I use `--backup-dir=BACKUPDIR`, it takes 15 Minutes displaying `sending incremental file list`" and then finishes without errors. Why is that so?

I need `BACKUPDIR` on the `TARGET` drive and outside `TARGET` directory. It works ok when there is something to backup. And the speed after the pause on start is normal.

Comment: I can't reproduce this locally. (a) What is the target filesystem? (b) When you say `SOURCE`, is that actually `SOURCE/`, i.e. a path that ends with a `/`?

Comment: The Filesystem is APFS (all) cause using Mac. I use the actual rsync Version and not the Version included MacOS. 
Source and Target Parameter with / at the end (directories). And both (Source/Target) are on external usb drives.